# Setting useImmersiveMode to true makes a moving sprite blink in a LibGDX game

Tags: libgdx, rendering, sprites

I'm developing a simple game where i have gravity and a body which jumps when i touch the screen and a sprite displaying in its position. All is good until i set `useImmersiveMode` to true on `AndroidLuncher` for the game to be in full screen. when i do that, while the body is moving ,the sprite is blinking all the time, when resting it's not.

Is there something that i missing?

Should i use a different way for displaying my game on a full screen?

Thanks

Comment: There are many things that could be wrong (including, but not limited to, how you draw sprites and how you set immerse mode), and without seeing some relevant code it's difficult to answer this question. Is there any more information you can add to your question?